# Starting with iPad Magazine App, how to make reader

Tags: ios, ipad

I need to start developing an app to publish interactive magazines for the iPad. However I don't have any idea how I can make the reader. I've been using web views to display normal pdf's, however now I need to use magazines created using Adobe Indesign. Have been looking all  over and haven't found anything besides businesses that already provide their own apps for publishing.

If anyone can point me somewhere I can start, I've already looked at a very good tutorial to set up the store and possibly the library:

http://ios-blog.co.uk/articles/tutorials/how-to-make-a-magazine-app-in-ios-part-i/

but i don't think QuickLook is what I need for the reader.

Comment: You could look at Mag+, free tools and affordable app price http://www.magplus.com/features-price/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this PDF rendering library:
http://pspdfkit.com/

We used it in a similar app, and were very pleased. Peter Steinberger (the author) also gives great support and is very helpful. Previous to purchasing this library, I wrote my own PDF renderer, and I can guarantee you that it's MUCH cheaper to just buy Pete's library. Otherwise, you will spend months to optimize it enough that it runs on iPad 1.